# Qt-creator and ncurses: initscr() not found

Tags: c++, qt-creator, ncurses

I am on Xubuntu x64 and I want to use ncurses in my software. This software is being build with Qt Creator 4.8. I have no problems including the ncurses.h file, but when I want to use functions of ncurses (initscr() and endwin()) I get the following errors:

> Undefined reference to 'endwin'
>
> Undefined reference to 'initscr'

What steps should I take to fix this problem?

I have installed the following ncurses related packages:

- libncurses5:amd64
- libncurses5:i386
- libncurses5-dbg
- libncurses5-dev
- libncursesw5:amd64
- libncursesw5:i386
- libncursesw5-dbg
- libncursesw5-dev
- ncurses-base
- ncurses-bin
- ncurses-examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out (finally)

The right way to do it: rightclick your project->add library -> system library
Here you need the path to the *.so file (so not *.so.5 or something), which was in my case 
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so`

Then add it and tadaaa: done.

Answer (score 1):

and I also found this guide may be it works, to me none has worked yet
http://www.lucidarme.me/?p=3961

"In the .pro file of the project, add the following line to specify to the compiler it has to use the ncurses library:

`LIBS += -lncurses`

To avoid the following error message : “Error opening terminal: unknown.”, add a variable in the run environment of Qt. Project -> Run -> Run environment -> add. Add a variable named TERM and set it of xterm."

UPD: my problem solved by checking the "Run in terminal" option in Projects->Run.